# Combining two vectors into a list of ordered pairs

Tags: r, list, vector

```
x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(6,7,8,9)
```

I want to create a list like this:

```
z = list(c(1,6),c(2,7),c(3,8),c(4,9))
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? I've searched and there are a lot of similar answers but they deal mostly with combining strings using `paste()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be

```
Map(c, x, y)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 7

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 8

#[[4]]
#[1] 4 9
```

---

Or with `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(x, y, c)
```

Comment: The later works. The first one returns an error. Thanks.

Comment: I am curious what would be the appropriate way to do this in base R, without using a loop.

Comment: @ZhaochenHe  May be you had a object identifier `c`.  Try to backquote it

Comment: Ah, it was because I used "map", instead of "Map".

Comment: @ZhaochenHe `map` is from `purrr` and it takes only single parameter. while `Map` is from `base R` and can take any number of parameters

Comment: Also see `purrr::transpose`.